# Dynamically use QGLWidget or QOpenGLWidget depending on Qt version

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, c-preprocessor, moc

My code is supposed to compile and run on platforms before and after Qt 5.4 where QOpenGLWidget was introduced, superseding QGLWidget. I thought I could write code like this to support both:

```
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 4, 0)
#  define USE_Q_OPEN_GL_WIDGET
#endif

#ifdef USE_Q_OPEN_GL_WIDGET
#  include <QOpenGLWidget>
#else
#  include <QGLWidget>
#endif

class GLWidget :
#ifdef USE_Q_OPEN_GL_WIDGET
    public QOpenGLWidget
#else
    public QGLWidget
#endif
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    [...]
```

But that will not fly because `moc` does not seem to understand the preprocessor directives and will generate code for the wrong class.

I tried to work around the problem by adding a `add_custom_command` directive to my `CMakeLists.txt` which would run `${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" -E -P -x c++-header ...` on the file before passing it to moc. But that doesn't seem to work either as the preprocessor will remove the magic `Q_OBJECT` line, indicating that indeed `moc` must be run *before* the C preprocessor is run.

What other options do I have?

Must I resort to having two nearly identical header files (except for two lines) and then choose the right one at build time in cmake?

*EDIT*

To test this problem, try out the following:

- on a Ubuntu trusty system which comes with qt 5.2.1 (you can create a chroot using `sudo debootstrap trusty ubuntu-trusty`) do:
- apt-get install libqt5opengl5-dev build-essential qttools5-dev qt5-default
- then create `glwidget.h` containing:

  ```
  #ifndef GLWIDGET_H
  #define GLWIDGET_H

  #include <QtGlobal>
  #if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 4, 0)
  #  define USE_Q_OPEN_GL_WIDGET
  #endif

  #ifdef USE_Q_OPEN_GL_WIDGET
  #  include <QOpenGLWidget>
  #else
  #  include <QGLWidget>
  #endif

  class GLWidget :
  #ifdef USE_Q_OPEN_GL_WIDGET
      public QOpenGLWidget
  #else
      public QGLWidget
  #endif
  {
      Q_OBJECT
  };
  #endif
  ```
- then run:

  ```
  $ moc -v
  moc 5.2.1
  $ moc glwidget.h | grep QGL || echo "not found"
  not found
  $ moc glwidget.h | grep QOpenGL >/dev/null && echo "found!"
  found!
  ```
- so you see that even though qt 5.2.1 does not have QOpenGL, moc interpretes the preprocessor directive that way
- we can change the version check to the much simpler

  ```
  #if QT_VERSION >= 0x050400
  ```
- if we try again with that check, then moc in qt 5.2.1 in Ubuntu trusty generates the right results
- so we think that we found the solution and try running moc from a more recent qt distribution on the same code. This time I'm using moc from qt 5.5.1 in Debian unstable and I get:

  ```
  $ moc -v
  moc 5.5.1
  $ moc glwidget.h | grep QOpen || echo "not found"
  not found
  $ moc foo.h | grep QGL > /dev/null && echo "found"
  found
  ```
- most funnily, if under qt 5.5.1 I turn the version check macro mack to using

  ```
  #if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 4, 0)
  ```
- then it does work!

So in summary, moc does understand some preprocessor directives but the ones it does understand are different between versions before and after qt 5.4. There does not seem to exist a common preprocessor directive that is understood by both. Thus I do not see a way to solve this problem using preprocessor directives.

Comment: Actually `moc` *does* understand (certain?) preprocessor directives. Is that your complete header?

Comment: Are you trying with Qt 5.4 and 5.x (x < 4), or with Qt 4.x? `moc` expands macros in Qt 5.

Comment: Again, is that your complete header? I'd like to have a complete testcase...

Comment: Not really, I didn't manage to find a Qt old enough. But I believe you may be encountering a genuine bug of moc's preprocessor in pre-5-5...

Comment: @peppe it's not hard to find an old enough qt. The most recent ubuntu long term release (as used in my example) has one. It wil also be supported until 2019, so it's not out of this world to target that qt version. But thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CMake to generate this header. Put this code into it:

```
#include <@GL_CLASS@>

class GLWidget : @GL_CLASS@
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    [...]
```

And then do this in CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(GL_CLASS <depending on Qt version>)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}) #this is because configure_file produces its output in the build dir
configure_file(yourheader.h output.h @ONLY)
```

Finally, use `#include "output.h"` in your code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you might want to write `public @GL_CLASS@` as private inheritance makes no sense with a Qt widget.